# how to make contents in an Iframe resposive?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, iframe, responsive-design

I do not know much about iframes (never really used them) and I am using it to display a form on one of our pages. Currently we are using wufoo forms and use their embed code, but our seo team discovered that the embed form is adding h1 tags to things that we do not want. So we are taking the form and putting it to our server.

I have the form created here http://tinyurl.com/qdtfu9g

I would like the form to look like this (embed code from wufoo) http://tinyurl.com/m7v833w

This is my poor attempt http://tinyurl.com/kfvshed

How could I make the contents inside the iframe responsive, like they have done with their embed code.

Only reason why I am using the iframe is there javascript and css files mess with the current theme, so I kept them separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the iframe (not the content) responsive:

```
iframe, object, embed {
        max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to remove the scrollbars then add the following settings:

```
frameborder='0' scrolling='no'
```

If you want to style the content within the iframe, i would recommend jQuery

```
iframe1.$('superclass').style.border = '1px solid #000000'
```

or

```
iframe1.$('superclass').addClassName('border')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make style: "@media ... " entries. Normally they are done within the ccs file. But if I understand it right, you want to do this manually within your form code?
In this case I would suggest, you prepare this in a separate editor window and copy&paste it into the form-file between

Example:

```
// min based
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
#divname {
color:green;
}
}

// or max based
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
#divname {
color:red;
}
}
```

by this you can manage all parts.

I think you haven't seen they have different designs within one css ?
Search for the @media tags and copy paste it.